# Proof for conjugacy and cycle structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $g, h \in S_{n}$
>   Then, g is conjugate to h IFF g and h have the same cycle structure.

I begin first by proving the only if condition:

g is conjugate to h and suppose that h is a permutation of m-cycle.
$g^{-1}hg = g^{-1}\left ( a_{1},a_{2},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,a_{m} \right )g$

By a theorem, we get $\left ( a_{1}^{g},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,a_{m}^{g} \right )$

This is just $h^{g}=\left ( a_{1}^{g},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,a_{m}^{g} \right )$

The element $h^{g}$ has m elements so has the same cycle structure the element h does.

Does this suffices?
If not, where should I take it?

To prove the converse,

suppose the element h in cycle decomposition is $h=\left ( a_{1},a_{2},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,a_{m} \right )\left ( b_{1}b_{2},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,b_{m} \right )\cdot \cdot \cdot  =\left ( A_{1}A_{2}\cdot \cdot \cdot  A_{m}\right )$
$\space$

and similarly the element g is $g=\left ( B_{1}B_{2}\cdot \cdot \cdot B_{m} \right )$

I'll like a useful hint to keep me going from here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This proof doesn't work because not all permutations are $m$-cycles for some $m$. What about $h=(1,2,3)(4,5)$?

I would prove this by induction. Every permutation can be written as the product of $2$-cycles, and the minimal number of $2$-cycles used is an important property of the permutation which is useful for induction.

The base case has $h=(a,b)$ for some $a$ and $b$ and can be resolved by casework.

Assume it's true for permutations that are the product of $m$ 2-cycles. Suppose $h=(a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_{m+1},b_{m+1})$. Then write $$ghg^{-1}=g^{-1}(a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_m,b_m)gg^{-1}(a_{m+1},b_{m+1})g$$ This produces two permutations, $p_1,p_2$ such that $p_1$ has the same structure as $(a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_{m},b_m)$, $p_2$ is a $2$-cycle, and $g=p_1p_2$. But then $p_1p_2$ has the same structure as $h$ because $p_1p_2$ is "something followed by a $2$-cycle" and $h$ is "that same something followed by a $2$-cycle".